# Getting data from the DOM to pass via link_to to a rails controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the following view in my rails app:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span11 center searchFieldContainer">
    <div class="span3">
        <%= collection_select :matchup, :player_1, Player.all, :id, :last_name, {}, { :multiple => false, class: "matchupSearchField", id: "player_1_search_field" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <h2>VS</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="span3">
        <%= collection_select :matchup, :player_2, Player.all, :id, :last_name, {}, { :multiple => false, class: "matchupSearchField", id: "player_2_search_field" } %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
  <%= link_to "View Matchup", 
    findMatchup_path(:player_1 => **ID_OF_PLAYER_1**, :player_2 => **ID_OF_PLAYER_1**),
    :method => :get, class: "my_class" %>
</div>
```

which is part of '/home.html.erb', my root_path.

How can I replace **ID_OF_PLAYER_1** in the link_to with the ID of the player selected in the collection_select above? Can I use jQuery to get the value of that collection_select field?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you have to use JS for that.

Comment: How would I get the JS into the ruby code before it hits the controller?

Comment: You won't. You have to build the query string part of the `href` by yourself. Your answer is the right thing to do though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_tag('/findMatchup', method: :get) do %>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span11 center searchFieldContainer">
        <div class="span3">
            <%= collection_select :matchup, :player_1, Player.all, :id, :last_name, {}, { :multiple => false, class: "matchupSearchField", id: "player_1_search_field" } %>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <h2>VS</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="span3">
            <%= collection_select :matchup, :player_2, Player.all, :id, :last_name, {}, { :multiple => false, class: "matchupSearchField", id: "player_2_search_field" } %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
    <%= submit_tag "View Matchup", class: "btn" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The controller accesses the variables using:

```
@player1 = Player.find(params[:matchup][:player_1])
```